# Flickr API Java/Clojure

Tags: java, api, clojure, flickr, flickrj

I am trying to get a list of all the photo sets in my account. I gave my application write access i can verify this has write access by creating an photo set but when ever i try to read the list i only get my public lists not my privates.

```
(def flickr (new Flickr api-key shared-sercret (new REST)))

(defn get-photo-sets [ ] 
  (let  [;prefs      (.getPrefsInterface flickr)
     user-id    (get-user-id) 
     photo-sets (.getPhotosets 
             (.getList (.getPhotosetsInterface flickr) user-id)) ]    
    (doseq [photo photo-sets] (println (.getTitle photo) ))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [discussions](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157613693408194/) I've seen on the API forums, you should be able to get a list of private photosets by making an authenticated call without passing in a userID to `getLists`.

The userID is optional and if it isn't specified, it uses the authenticated user.  The fact that it returns public in one case but private in another isn't too clearly documented from where I stand.

Hope this helps.